# React Native: Creating and passing a StackNavigator to a Bottom Tab Navigator

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I was trying to use my new created navigator stack on my bottom navigator tabs item so that I can use it instead of a regular screen.

So far I created the new stack navigator:

```
const FavoritesNav = () => {
return(
    <FavoritesStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontSize: 17
            }
        }}>
        <FavoritesStack.screen
            name="Favorite"
            component={FavoritesScreen}
        />
        <FavoritesStack.screen
            name="MealDetail"
            component={MealDetailScreen}
        />
    </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
);
```

};

And then, I tried to pass this on one of the item of my bottom navigator:

```
<MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesNav}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
```

This throws me an error: `A navigator can only contain 'Screen' components as its diection children (found [object, object])`

How can I pass my newly created stack to the bottom tab nav?

PS. Here's my complete code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

import { Ionicons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import { Platform } from 'react-native';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';

import CategoriesScreen from '../screens/CategoriesScreen';
import CategoryMealsScreen from '../screens/CategoryMealsScreen';
import MealDetailScreen from '../screens/MealDetailScreen';

import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

import HeaderButton from '../components/HeaderButton';
import { HeaderButtons, Item } from 'react-navigation-header-buttons';

import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';

import { CATEGORIES } from '../data/dummy-data';

import Colors from '../constants/colors';

const MealsNav = createStackNavigator();

const MealsNavigator = () => {
    return (
        <MealsNav.Navigator
            mode="modal"
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}
        >
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="Categories"
                component={CategoriesScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meals Categories'
                }}

            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="CategoryMeals"
                component={CategoryMealsScreen}
                options={({ route }) => {
                    const catId = route.params.categoryId;
                    const selectedCategory = CATEGORIES.find((cat) => cat.id === catId);

                    return {
                        title: selectedCategory.title,
                    };

                }}
            />
            <MealsNav.Screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
                options={{
                    title: 'Meal Detail',
                    headerRight: () => (
                        <HeaderButtons HeaderButtonComponent={HeaderButton}>
                            <Item
                                title='Favorite'
                                iconName='ios-star'
                                onPress={() => console.log('Mark as the favorite')}
                            />
                        </HeaderButtons>
                    ),
                }}
            />
        </MealsNav.Navigator>
    );
};

const MealsFavTabNavigator =
    Platform.OS === 'android'
        ? createMaterialBottomTabNavigator()
        : createBottomTabNavigator();

const getNavigationOptions = () => {
    if (Platform.OS === 'ios') {
        // Props for the ios navigator
        return {
            labeled: false,
            initialRouteName: 'Meals',
            tabBarOptions: {
                activeTintColor: 'tomato',
                inactiveTintColor: 'black',
            },
        };
    }
    // Props for android
    return {
        initialRouteName: 'Favorites',
        activeColor: 'tomato',
        inactiveColor: 'black',
        barStyle: { backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor },
        shifting: true
    };
};

const MealsTabNav = () => {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator {...getNavigationOptions()} >
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Meals"
                    component={MealsNavigator}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-restaurant" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
                <MealsFavTabNavigator.Screen
                    name="Favorites"
                    component={FavoritesNav}
                    options={{
                        tabBarIcon: ({ focused, color, size }) => (
                            <Ionicons name="ios-star" size={25} color={focused ? "tomato" : "black"} />
                        )
                    }}
                />
            </MealsFavTabNavigator.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
};

const FavoritesStack = createStackNavigator();

const FavoritesNav = () => {
return(
    <FavoritesStack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: {
                backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
            },
            headerTintColor: '#fff',
            headerTitleStyle: {
                fontSize: 17
            }
        }}>
        <FavoritesStack.screen
            name="Favorite"
            component={FavoritesScreen}
        />
        <FavoritesStack.screen
            name="MealDetail"
            component={MealDetailScreen}
        />
    </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
);
```

};

```
export default MealsTabNav;
```

Thanks for those who will help.

Answer (score 1):

Guess you are importing `FavoritesScreen` but using `FavoriteScreen` in code.

```
import FavoritesScreen from '../screens/FavoritesScreen';

const FavoritesNav = () => {
    <NavigationContainer>
        <FavoritesStack.Navigator
            screenOptions={{
                headerStyle: {
                    backgroundColor: Colors.primaryColor,
                },
                headerTintColor: '#fff',
                headerTitleStyle: {
                    fontSize: 17
                }
            }}>
            <FavoritesStack.screen
                name="Favorite"
                component={FavoritesScreen}
            />
            <FavoritesStack.screen
                name="MealDetail"
                component={MealDetailScreen}
            />
        </FavoritesStack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
};
```

Comment: I fixed i using your sugestion but it returned this error `A navigator can only contain 'Screen' components as its diection children (found [object, object])`

Comment: @JonesSmith You have to use FavoritesStack.Screen instead of FavoritesStack.screen the s should be capital

Comment: @GuruparanGiritharan you're the man! Smart as always!

Comment: You are welcome, i guess this answer solves your initial problem :)